# How to sort the array in a loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a loop where my array gets stored and also need to check and display the content which should not get repeated. For eg:

```
 Loop
 {
    $myarray = storecontent
    for($i=0 ; $i<count($myarray) ; $i++)
      {
         if($myarray == storecontent)
          {

          }else
          {
            display content;
          }
      }

  }
```

I ve did something like that , where a page is in a loop and that page has details of each post, in that few have similar content,
i need to display like

```
Content1:
    my_post1;
    my_post2;
Content2:
    my_post1;
    my_post2;
```

Comment: you can use sort() function ... to sort array..

Comment: there are lots of variations of sort(), with different sorting characteristics.  Like sorting by the name of the key or name of the value.

Comment: what is your array structure ?

Comment: my array structure is array([0]=>"content1" [1]=>"content2" [3]=>"content1")...

Comment: my array has contents which are repeated, since the page is in a loop, when i print the content it prints every time the loop runs... so i need to avoid re printing of the content again even though its in a loop

Answer (score 1):

use [PHP array sort function](https://www.php.net/sort) to sort arrays alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
    $myarray = array_unique($myarray);
    sort($myarray);
    foreach($myarray as $ele){
       echo $ele;
    }
?>
```

Comment: my array has contents which are repeated, since the page is in a loop, when i print the content it prints every time the loop runs... so i need to avoid re printing of the content again even though its in a loop

Comment: `array_unique($myarray)` removes repeated values.So you dont need to worry about reptead values.

Comment: This will prints sorted unique contents in an array.